# How to identify a clicked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

#### Thanks everyone for helping  me find out, that it was a ridiculous mistake. I had two versions of the html file and the version I was working with had *no* IDs specified for the img-tags. JQuery was right, when it told me that the IDs were undefined. What you see below does work perfectly.

I can't find a working solution on this one:

```
    $('.iconf').live('tap', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert (id); //this alerts "undefined"
    });
```

There are three `<img>`-Tags with different IDs (attributes) which have the class "iconf". This is my HTML:

```
    <img class="iconf" id="bad" src="img/icons/icon_rate_circle.png"/>
    <img class="iconf" id="ok" src="img/icons/icon_rate_circle.png"/>
    <img class="iconf" id="good" src="img/icons/icon_rate_circle.png"/>
```

Can you help me get this working?

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work. Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I added the used lines of html

Comment: Could you give a link to your site so we can see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code

- http://jsfiddle.net/QpXL6/1/

JS

```
$('.iconf').live('tap', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert (id); 
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="iconf" id="bad" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/120658_38581_64_windows_icon.png"/>
<img class="iconf" id="ok" src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100620154531/en.linux/images/3/3d/Tux-icon.png"/>
<img class="iconf" id="good" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/120611_38534_64_apple_icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with mobile Safari, then the source of your problem may be the buggy jquery live implementation on that platform: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677

Comment: I've tested the above code on Safari (OS X), mobile Safari and Firefox 3.6.6 (OS X). Always "undefined" is alerted and really don't know where my mistake is

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell the result please:

```
$('img.iconf').click(function() {
   var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(itemId);
});
```

Comment: this still alerts "undefined"